# There is a hole where the handle on my bifold doors goes. How do I fix it?

Tags: doors

The door handles were loose and they kept coming off and eventually they made a hole in the door and I am not able to put the back on.

Comment: Pictures.  Let us see the hole.

Comment: Right—is the hole simply the hole left by whatever was fastening the handles to the door, now that they're gone?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as though the handle kept coming loose. As it was used without being tightened, it enlarged the hole in the door and now the hole is too large for the screw head to hold the handle in place. If that's the case, carry on. Otherwise, this is totally off-base because the question was incomplete.

---

The simplest way is with washers. This will work if you're not too concerned about looks.

Supplies:

- 2 washers.

  - The inside diameter should just clear the threads of the screw holding the handle on, the outside diameter should be a bit bigger (to a lot bigger - depends on how much longer you want it to last and how little you care about appearance).
- Screwdriver

Process:

- Put the screw through one washer
- Put the screw through the hole in the door
- Put the other washer on the screw
- Screw the handle on.
- Tighten.

When snugged up tightly, the washers will prevent the screw head from pulling through the hole in the door again. But, this will likely look ugly and is obviously a kludge.

---

A neater, longer lasting, better looking fix would be to plug the hole with a dowel and drill a new mounting hole

Supplies:

- A short length of wooden dowel that is slightly larger than the current hole in the door.
- A drill bit of the same diameter as the dowel you've just purchased
- A drill bit that's *just* larger than the outside diameter of the threads of the handle's screw.
- Wood glue.

  - This can be a small bottle of simple yellow carpenter's glue. Nothing fancy is needed here.
- A saw to cut the dowel to length.

Process:

- Carefully drill out the hole in the door to make it match the diameter of the dowel.
- Cut a piece of dowel the same length as the door's thickness.
- Coat the dowel and hole in the door with some glue
- Insert the dowel into the hole, ensure it's flush on both sides.

  - Wipe up the glue that squeezes out with a damp sponge or paper towel. Much easier to remove the glue now than after it dries.
  - Wait *at least* as long as the directions say for the glue to dry.
  - If you didn't cut the dowel accurately, make sure it's flush on the *outside* of the door where the handle will be.
- Once the glue has dried, use the smaller drill bit to drill a new hole for the screw.
- Slip the screw through the new hole and screw on the door handle.
- Again, if the dowel wasn't the correct length:

  - If it was too long your screw may now be too short. Either get a longer screw or cut some of the dowel off the inside of the door.
  - If the dowel was too short, the screw may tighten within the handle but not be snug enough to hold the handle. Use some small washers to fill up the extra space on the back side of the door.

Answer (score 1):

Normal approach is to drill all the way through (assuming it was a wood-screw type connection that went into wood) and use a machine screw from the other side instead. If it was a machine screw from the other side to begin with, you add a washer to it. Some thread-locking compound would also be indicated to stop it from coming loose yet again.

You could also drill out the hole and glue in a plug of wood, then screw the handle in again after the glue dries.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking what you have is a hollow core door and the screw has pulled through the back side.

There will be no way to glue in a dowel, or make a plug.

What you need is a fender washer as presented [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KM4LIPU)

Available at most all hardware stores.

If the front side has a hole that has enlarged as well use a washer there too.  They can be painted to match the door or compliment the knob.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to put a threaded insert into the door and then screw the handle to that.

Comment: "insert",  edit: insert "insert"